# If a value is presente only one time

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column (C8:C17) with names, some names are named 2 or 3 times, I just want to releave names that are here only one time and put it in column H.

For example:
In column C8 to C17:

```
John
Bob
Dylan
Vanessa
Meryll
Bob
Vanessa
John
John
Bob
```

I should have in column H:

```
Dylan
Meryll
```

This is my code:

```
Sub Macro2()
'Names
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("c8:c17")) = 1 Then
        For i = 8 To 17
            Cells(i, 8) = "x"   'the name that is names only one time
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Therefore you need to show (the code) what you have tried so far. Please read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Yes I understand, but I am conscient that is an eas code of 2- lignes, I can show you all my code but It will not help. I tried something with the " If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("c8:c17"), "=1") Then"

Comment: Please don't post code in comments [edit] your question instead. Post your full working code (if possible a [mcve]) not only half of a line! Tell us exactly … (1) what your code actually does and what you expect your code should do. (2) Where you got stuck. (3) What error messages you get, and where in the code. People here are not here to solve your issue we are here to help you to solve your issue yourself. So your collaboration is needed to solve it. What you need at first is a plan (in steps) what you think your code should do (in words).

Comment: You've no criteria in your attempt, it should be `countif(range,criteria)=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through your whole range, to check how often every cell value is found.

```
Option Explicit 'First line in a Module to ensure all variables are declared

Sub FindSingleNamesOnly()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'we qualify our worksheet

    Dim rngSearchIn As Range
    Set rngSearchIn = ws.Range("C8:C17") 'we set the range we want to search in

    Dim iRow As Long 'this is our row counter
    iRow = 8 'we set the row where we start filling in the single sames

    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In rngSearchIn 'we loop through all cells within the search range
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSearchIn, rngCell.Value) = 1 Then
            '… and check if the cell value of the actual cell is found only once
            ws.Cells(iRow, "H").Value = rngCell.Value 'write the single value to the new column
            iRow = iRow + 1 'move writing row one forward
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I know If a name is present in even ?

Comment: @babou sorry I didn't understand your question. Please be more specific.

Comment: No problem, for exemple Bob in the column is mentionned 3 times , it's an odd number. There is a way to know that ?

Comment: @babou `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSearchIn, rngCell.Value)` returns the count of a name and `x Mod 2 = 0` is true for even numbers: So `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSearchIn, rngCell.Value) Mod 2 = 0 Then EVEN Else ODD`